# How to get value of Shortcode when its appended to URL and Stored in Database

Tags: php, wordpress, append, affiliate

I stored the url in Database
https://example.in/register/?ref=[affiliate_id]
and I tried to get the affiliate id of current logged in user.But I am unable to get the value when I print it.
But if I used as directly like using 
$val = do_shortcode('[[affiliate_id]');
 I am getting the value.
Please solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but use below code it might be resolved your problem

```
 add_action('init','runShortcode');

 function runShortcode(){
  $getCode = $_request['ref'];
  If($getCode)
  {
     $shirtcodes = '['.$getCode.']';

     echo do_shortcode($shirtcides);
  }
```

Not sure with code